# Publish exe using installshield

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, plugins, vlc

I made my application in vb and it runs smoothly.
I now have to publish it to use in others pc.
How to get a working exe ?
I've tried with Visual Studio - other projects - install shield but when it builds
displays the following warnings:

```
Warning 1   -7235: InstallShield could not create the software identification tag because the Tag Creator ID setting in the General Information view is empty.  ISEXP : warning : -7235: InstallShield could not create the software identification tag because the Tag Creator ID setting in the General Information view is empty.

Warning 2   -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework.  It is recommended that the release include the .NET Framework. ISEXP : warning : -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework.  It is recommended that the release include the .NET Framework.

Warning 3   -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component AxInterop.AXVLC.dll ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component AxInterop.AXVLC.dll

Warning 4   -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component AxInterop.AXVLC.dll1    ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component AxInterop.AXVLC.dll1

Warning 5   -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component Interop.AXVLC.dll   ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component Interop.AXVLC.dll

Warning 6   -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component Interop.AXVLC.dll1  ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component Interop.AXVLC.dll1

Warning 7   -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component SjCam_Remote.exe    ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component SjCam_Remote.exe

Warning 8   -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component SjCam_Remote.exe1   ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file axvlc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component SjCam_Remote.exe1
```

The app uses VLC plugin.
The app works fine in the maker pc. 
Blocks when Vlc is requested in others pc. 
(net framework 4.5 is installed)

p.s. if i use the visual studio publish function, the result is the same.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Maybe it's telling you the truth. Do you have a reference to that dll?

Comment: Honestly, i don't even know how to do that.. :(
I thought it was going to do it automatically. So i can tell i have to read and figure it out how to do it.

Any tips ?

Comment: I just checked. There's no axvlc.dll added to the references. There are 2 vlc plugins tho (Interop.AXVLC.dll and AxInterop.AXVLC.dll)
I tried to manually add axlc.dll but it won't load.. :/
Help needed !!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the solution (don't know about VLC) but it seems you at least now know what the problem is (no reference). Looks like it's a COM reference, though. Try the COM tab of "Add Reference" (if there is such a thing in VB.NET).

Comment: Yep.. COM reference.. Like i said, VLC plugins are referenced. But still it asks for axvlc.dll. (and if i try to add it manually it won't load.. :(
http://i.imgur.com/BIP1ty3.jpg

Thanks for the help tho.. Waiting for someone knowning the VLC plugin..

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with a reference that i added in a dropbox folder. now the reference remains in the dropbox (O:) path. I had to remove manually from regedit the reference for it. crossing fingers it will not damage Visual Studio references. The main issue is that VS (i am writing in C#) is using 2 dlls. Interop.AXVLC and AxInterop.AXVLC that is crappy.

This may occur if you change the Build mode, to 64bit machines. Actually this day i am using vlc 2.1.0 that did partially the trick.